# Subtraction of Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X \sim N(1, 2)$ and $Y \sim N(1, 2)$. Find 2 possibilities for the distribution of the difference $Z=X-Y$. State the conditions for each to apply.

The only possibility I could think of was $Z\sim N(0, 4)$. Can anyone suggest another possibility? The next part asks for the standardized form of $Z$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I'm not too sure what the answer would be for this either.

Comment: Consider $Z$ when $Y=X$

Comment: So then we'd just get 0?

Comment: What about the standardized form in the next part?

Comment: You have made an  assumption in your $Z \sim N(0,4)$ example.  Can you state it?

Comment: Would it be $X \neq Y$?

Comment: Your assumption is rather stronger than that.  In fact you may have assumed $X$ and $Y$ are independent